# Error showing while uploading theme in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried to install a wordpress theme using upload option in wordpress. However when I upload it the following error message is showing.

```
The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Invalid archive structure
```

Please help with the possible solutions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like the zip file you are uploading either isn't a zip file or is corrupt.

Try re-downloading the theme from the source and then try uploading again.

Answer (score 8):

I had same issue on php 7.2 |ubuntu 18.04 | wordpress 5.2,  then I install php7.2-zip using 
`apt install php7.2-zip` according to some research
***but it didn't fix theme update issue*** from back-end. Then I installed php curl using `sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl` and that fix the issue.

***php curl for ubuntu:***

- *PHP 7.2:* sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl
- *PHP 7.1:* sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl
- *PHP 7.0:* sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
- *PHP 5.6:* sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl
- *PHP 5.5:* sudo apt-get install php5.5-curl
- *If you don't know your php version:* sudo apt-get install php-curl

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.3-curl`now