# Wordpress theme upload error PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, mbstring, pclzip

I'm new to php as well as wordpress however because of some need I had to work with wordpress only. So just to start I read a tutorial and created a wordpress theme of my own and when I tried to upload my theme I got the below error:

```
The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
```

Searching for the same I've found that usually the cause of such an error is maximum available space or upload file size issue. However since I'm working on localhost I don't think it could be the case. Moreover I've increased the `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` and `memory_limit` as well. But still I'm getting the same error.

I'm using Wordpress 3.5.2.

Comment: Try uploading the files manually to your theme folder - `/wp-content/themes/yourThemeFolder/`

Comment: @AmalMurali its working that way. I need to make it work using wordpress theme upload option so that I may not get into trouble while uploading the theme on server.

Comment: I've experienced this when specifying certain `mbstring.*` values, it maybe worth giving those a once over.

Comment: @AnthonySterling I guess `mbstring.*` is in `php.ini` right ? I don't think I've made any changes there, can you elaborate what was the issue and how you resolved it ?

Comment: Sadly not, I did not investigate further. Here's my default, custom, php.ini settings: http://pastie.org/8160888 removing the `mbstring.*` settings resolved the issue you describe.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This error due to you are trying to upload Other than `ZIP` Compressed version. Other format is not supported while uploading the plugin in wordpress.

You should unzip your plugin and make sure you compress with `ZIP` format and upload it will be working fine.

Comment: Thankyou. I was making .rar file instead of .zip

Comment: That was my problem too. Thank you.

Comment: Wordpress will complain on some environments and not others even though it's a valid ZIP, it seems to depend on server environment

Comment: I had same issue. but I'm **able to fix it after installing curl** [read more information from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56987412/3440497)

Answer (score 2):

One of simple alternative is to download theme package, upzip it and upload through FTP whole theme folder into

```
/wp-content/themes
```

Then go to Admin CP and switch to new installed theme.

Comment: I already kept the theme folder inside `/wp-content/themes/` only and it worked that way. However just to check I did same on my another system and on uploading I'm getting the same issue. So I was just worried that I might get the same issue while uploading the theme on my web hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

please check that only those file are here that you wan to upload. i was getting same problem, then i search on folder, there was already zip folder in it. after uploading that zip  file. the problem was solved. Now the themes is activated.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem while trying to install Wordpress plugin from the Wordpress interface. Turns out the disk space quota was full for that specific account. I went to WHM manager and increased the quota and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I had the zip-plugin not installed. For Ubuntu/Debian and php7.4 (Bionic) you can use

```
apt-get install php7.4-zip
service php7.4-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was installing plugins for a theme. It appeared that in the meantime plugins' download url had changed, updating it solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I found one more case which may help you.

It throws the same error if the zip file is `incomplete` or `corrupt`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are uploading the theme as a ".rar" file.

Convert the theme into ".zip" file and then upload it to your site.

For converting into the ".zip":

1. Right-click on the folder of your theme folder.
2. Select "Send to".
3. Click on "Compressed (zipped) folder".
4. Upload ".zip" file to your WordPress site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it turned out the problem was that the virtual server had exceeded its quota. (I'm using Virtualmin, and had a 1GB quota on that website's virtual server).

After increasing the quota, the problem went away.