# How to fix Broken theme

Tags: wordpress-theming

I uploaded a theme manually and I get this message:

```
"Template is missing. Standalone themes need to have a index.php template file. 
Child themes need to have a Template header in the style.css stylesheet."
```

And when I upload directly from Wordpress I get this message:

```
"The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature"
```

Like I have shown, I have tried uploading it manually and directly and neither of those work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771578/wordpress-theme-upload-error-pclzip-err-bad-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress theme upload error PCLZIP\_ERR\_BAD\_FORMAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771578/wordpress-theme-upload-error-pclzip-err-bad-format)